# Getting Point mysql Column in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Im having a problem getting the point value of a table in mysql in Laravel 5.2.

My table is called places and my point column is called location. When I get a place

```
$place = Place::find(1);
```

and then I do a

```
var_dump($place->location)
```

to see whats on there I get

```
string(25) "y���AtA�ެ���L�"
```

And if I do

```
utf8_encode($place->location)
```

I get

```
string(35) "y®ïÃAtAÀÞ¬ÁûªLÀ"
```

How do I get the latitude and longitude from this string?. Or what else do I have to do to manage point columns in Laravel?

The column location is filled from mysql command line, like this.
For example:

```
UPDATE places set location = POINT('70','50') where id = 1;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're going to have to give more detail. How does data get into this column in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse it with: [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

You should also make sure your database config has the 'charset' set to 'utf8'

```
// config/database.php
'charset'  => 'utf8',
```

Comment: Its not working, now I get string(35) "y®ïÃAtAÀÞ¬ÁûªLÀ"